# agency communications with employer

Tags: human-resources, employer-relations, employer

Perhaps an odd question.  I work for a really good company (very friendly) through an agency.  Today was my birthday. I received well wishes from my recruiter.

**Is it common practice for my recruiter to also communicate my birthday to my employer?**  I ask because I don't want my employer to know; they have a policy of ordering lunch and I really don't like the attention.  So I'm nervous.

Comment: I wouldn't think this would be common practice but if you're worried about it, just tell the recruiter you don't want the company to know your birthday.

Comment: That's the bets thing to do, although I would be certain that the company already has this for their HR files. That said, in "several" decades of contracting, the company has ***never*** mentioned my birthday.

Comment: Your birthday is already with them; Like it or not. You cannot stop that. Only think you can do is ask them  not to "celebrate" it.

Comment: I worry requesting the recruiter not mention it may weird the recruiter out a bit?  If it helps I'm a temp at the company?

Answer (score 3):

If this worries you, then just ask the agency not to mention it, although I would be certain that the company already has your details, including date of birth, for their HR files.

That said, in "several" decades of contracting, the company has ***never*** mentioned my birthday.

I also don't bring anything into the office on my birthday, and don't partake of any cake, sweets, etc brought by those who do.

In all of those decades, no team mate has ever asked me when my birthday is.

Btw, while I understand not liking to be in the limelight, please do be sure to be a good mixer, aka team player. It is  a necessary skill, no matter how shy one is.

Answer (score -1):

It is not at all common practice to wish employee on birthdays,  however , in my opinion it is very good gesture and source of motivation for the employee.  It is not understandable for me that why you didn't like it.I think if someone wants to involve himself in your special days than it should be appreciated.